# Probability Distribution of a Self-Dependent Function

Tags: probability

Suppose a function $f(x)$ that outputs the probability of an event happening. It is defined as:
$f(x)=1-(\frac{1}{2})^{\Delta x}$ where $\Delta x= x-$(The $x$ value of the last time the event happened). What would the distribution of $f(x)$look like? (Apologies for any bad terminology used in this question).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory

Comment: Indeed this seems to describe a renewal process with interarrival times $\tau_i$ with distribution $$P(\tau=n)=\left(1-2^{-n}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{-k}$$ for every positive integer $n$.